# Android application freezing on splash screen when recording roboscripts through android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, unreal-engine4, firebase-test-lab

For whatever reason whenever I try to run the "Record Roboscript" launch mode in Android Studio to record a roboscript, the application hangs on the splash screen activity and does not continue it's load. All other launch variants launch without an issue (Normal launch, debug, launch and then attach debugger all work without an issue), but the Record Roboscript launch mode does not. I've pulled the logs from the device and it doesn't seem to have any warnings or errors relevant to the issue, but I'll paste them below as well if it might be helpful.

Are there any settings I can try to apply to rectify this issue? Any ports that I can try to open?

Comment: You tagged this with "unreal-engine4". Is this suggesting that your app is a Unity game? Robo may not work too well in that case.

Comment: Yep our game is a Unreal Engine 4 Game. Unfortunately because of the requirements that google is putting on us for publishing, we need to be able to automate our login. But more unfortunately we cannot log in using their resource lookup on the app for the login fields. As such they seemed to recommend to use a roboscript to automate the login process. Is there another way to record a roboscript for this? Page in question: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en  Edit: Although on further review it appears they are requesting a "Game Loop" instead.

Comment: If you want to talk to the Test Lab engineers about this, join the Firebase Slack in the #test-lab channel. https://firebase.community/

Comment: Absolutely, Thank you so much @DougStevenson!